# Batman Arkham City freezes when searching for Mr. Freeze

Tags: technical-issues, batman-arkham-city

Oh, the irony!

I'm at the part where you search for Mr. Freeze. On my way to the museum, the game freezes, and sometimes crashes with an error message about missing files.

I've Googled and found that others have this problem as well, but found no solution.

**Note: I am not using the Steam version**

What I've tried:

- Lowering the display settings to the very minimum.
- Fiddling with the sound, in case there's a missing file there for some reason.
- Re-installing the game.
- Make sure the game is only run on 2 processors and not 4.

Has anyone experienced the problem and managed to solve it?

#### EDIT:

Related: **[This question over at Yahoo! Answers is the exact problem I'm having.](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111223121413AAY08c2)**

Comment: See [the issues and fixes section at the PC Gaming Wiki's "Batman: Arkham City" article](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Batman:_Arkham_City#Issues_.26_Fixes).

Comment: @galacticninja: Anything specific? I'll try that quad fix (Even though I don't think I have quad cores). Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I'd try that. I'd also try [verifying the integrity of game cache files](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Batman:_Arkham_City#Gray_screen_after_fight_with_Joker) if you're playing the Steam version of the game. (Note: I currently don't have Arkham City)

Comment: If it still didn't work, be sure to update this question with the things that you've tried.

Comment: @galacticninja: Added :( I think I'll have to download a pirated version just to get the missing files. I'll see how that goes...

Comment: Are you using the Steam version? If yes, [see my comment here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92521/batman-arkham-city-freezes-when-searching-for-mr-freeze#comment126313_92521). Also, add info if you're using the Steam version of the game or not in your question.

Comment: @galacticninja: Added, this isn't the steam version (I can't seem to find it either), maybe not available to Israel..?

Comment: Have you applied all available patches etc.? This would be easier if it's available on steam for you, if not, there are plenty of torrents of updated versions of the game you could copy without cracking.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I actually gave up on it a bit for now, I have stuff to do, but I'll update should I find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth seeing if you can activate your serial code (presuming you got one with the game) on Steam. The game utilises Steamworks on Steam, so there's a small chance that might work. Once that's done, just install it on Steam (and yes, Steam should ignore region locks if you have a valid product code, I think) and see if that works.

I have absolutely no idea if that'll work for you, as retail code activation doesn't always work for games that don't force you to use Steam anyway, but it's probably worth a shot..

Answer (score 0):

The game freezes and glitches on PS3 during that Boss fight too. For me personally it froze once, and glitched to where I couldn't complete the fight twice in different playthroughs. Due to it happening on PS3 and PC it seems to be some sort of bug in the game itself.

If the game crash message tells you the actual names of the files missing you should do a search on your computer for them just to make sure they are there. If they are you may need to copy them to another folder in the system folders. I have had to do that before for several PC games.